# Enterprise Architect TypeScript reverse code engineering

Tags: typescript, uml, enterprise-architect

Does anyone have an idea if there is a way to get an EA model created from TypeScript code? Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect has Javascript as a supported language but I need to create my UML model entities to be created from Typescript code.

Anyone knows an existing project or do I have to start an own MDG adventure?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no native support for this language (you might try to pretend it were JavaScript source, but I doubt it will work). So the only way is to define your own language using the BNF language description that comes with EA. There are not too many people using it, so you will be mostly on your own when going this path. Sparx' support is helpful, but I guess it will not be an easy way.